# Auto select drop-down in php form using mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am facing issue to set the Auto drop down in my php form.

while selecting the QC Type, it should automatically select QC Code from MySQL Database. At the moment, i am selecting it manually. Can anyone help.

**php Form :**

[image]

```
<tr>
            <td align="right"><b>QC Code</b></td>
            <td> 
            <select name="qc_code" >
                 <option>Select a QC Code</option>

                         <?php 
    $get_qc = "select * from qctype";

$run_qc = mysqli_query($con, $get_qc);

while ($row_qctype=mysqli_fetch_array($run_qc)){    


    $qccode_title = $row_qctype['qccode_title'];

echo "<option value='$qccode_title'>$qccode_title</option>";


}
```

**Database : -**

[image]

Comment: Yes, I am using the following form. Let me know if require more details.

<form action="insert_qc.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

Comment: If you see my image (php form) there is a QC Type and QC Code. Currently, i am selecting QC Code manually. What I want to do is

When i select QC Type, it should automatically select QC Code in next drop-down. I belive qctype_id will be helpful in this.

Can you please share the code here.

Comment: Can this help ? I didn't get you ?

echo "<option value='$qccode_title'>$qccode_title</option>";

Comment: I want to achieve qccode_title automatically in this drop-down if i select qctype_title.

Answer (score 1):

You should put the title into the `value` instead. This way the `title` will be displayed and the value will be submitted.

```
$qccode_title = $row_qctype['qccode_title'];
$qctype_title = $row_qctype['qctype_title'];
echo "<option value='$qctype_title'>$qccode_title</option>";
```

Comment: I am getting the value by selecting manually. I have the same code which you have mentioned. This is not allowing me automatic drop-down for qccode_title. The functionality remain same with this

Comment: The functionality can't be the same. This has two different fields, your form have the same twice.

Comment: I mean, it is working as it was first by your provided code. No changes effected.

Comment: You don't need the `qc code` field anymore. Submit the form and access `$_POST['qc_code']` and the code will be there. The `value` has the value and the element will display the title.

Comment: @HirenParghi https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: After i have added another qctype, database only adding the new one. I am not able to find the previous qctype in database even i am adding it.